# If my license plates are thrown to the dumpster, do I need to report them as lost?

Tags: canada, identity-theft, license-plates

I lived in three provinces in Canada and kept the license plates that I had in all of them for personal collection purposes. Then I moved to France, leaving some of my things at a friend's (or so I thought) place. Now the "friend" turned toxic, so he may bring my items to a dumpster before I arrange for them to be shipped away from his place. I'm not particularly very concerned about my items, except for the license plates. If my old license plates turn up in the dumpster and someone picks them up and abuses them, could this possibly get me in trouble?

That being said, what is the best I can do to prevent any possible bad scenario? Do I need to report the plates "lost", just in case, even before they end up in the dumpster?

Comment: Car plates are regulated at the provincial level, so it depends on what those provinces are.